# Why is c++ object created through JNI no longer valid in subsequent calls?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to write a JNI wrapper around a third-party c++ library so it can be used directly from Java. The code examples that follow show the pattern I've been using to wrap the c++ objects. I've used this pattern successfully several times, but one object is giving me SIGSEGV every time I try to call methods on it.

The major difference is that in the classes that are working, I'm calling new WhateverNativeType() myself and returning the pointer address, but in the one that's failing I'm calling a factory method that's doing some logic to construct the class. When I copy that factory code into my method and call new myself, it fixes the problem and I don't get the SIGSEGV any more.

So, it looks like when I call the factory method, I can use the object within my method, but once my method returns that reference is no longer valid. I thought maybe it was getting garbage collected in the handful of milliseconds between my calls to createNativeObject() and getVersion(), so I tried putting it into a static vector, but that didn't help.

My question is, why is the native object going out of scope after my createNativeObject() method returns? Is there a way I can make it continue to be usable without bypassing the factory method?

My Java class looks like this:

```
package com.example.jni;

public class Example {
    private static final native long createNativeObject();
    private static final native String getVersion(long address);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long address = createNativeObject();
        System.out.println("Version: " + getVersion(address);
    }
}
```

My C++ code looks like this:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "com_example_jni_Example.h"
#include <third_party_stuff.hpp>

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_Example_createNativeObject(
        JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jClass) {
    std::cout << "createNativeObject()\n";
    thirdparty::NativeObject obj = thirdparty::NativeObjectCreator().create();
    std::cout << "Object: " << &obj << "\n";
    std::cout << "Version: " << obj.getVersion() << "\n";
    return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(&obj);
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_Example_getVersion(
        JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jClass, jlong address) {
    std::cout << "getVersion()\n";
    thirdparty::NativeObject *obj = 
        reinterpret_cast<thirdparty::NativeObject *>(address);
    std::cout << "Object: " << obj << "\n";
    std::cout << "Version: " << obj->getVersion() << "\n";
    return jenv->NewStringUTF(obj->getVersion().c_str());
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
createNativeObject()
Object: 0x7f9d07e52060
Version: 19154
getVersion()
Object: 0x7f9d07e52060

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f4e684c8b4a, pid=6683, tid=0x00007f4e868c9700
```

The native object in this case wraps a pointer to an abstract type and delegates all of its method calls to that thing. The factory method looks like this:

```
NativeObject NativeObjectCreator::create() {
    INativeObjectPtr ptr = decideWhichSubclassToUse();
    return NativeObject(ptr);
}
```

My working version of Java_com_example_jni_Example_createNativeObject looks like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_example_jni_Example_createNativeObject(
        JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jClass) {
    std::cout << "createNativeObject()\n";
    thirdparty::INativeObjectPtr ptr = 
            thirdparty::NativeObjectCreator.decideWhichSubclassToUse();
    thirdparty::NativeObject *obj = new thirdparty::NativeObject(ptr);
    std::cout << "Object: " << obj << "\n";
    std::cout << "Version: " << obj->getVersion() << "\n";
    return reinterpret_cast<jlong>(obj);
}
```

Comment: you have answered your own question in the second example. All you need to do is split it into two as in your first example, returning the pointer from the factory class. When the first method exits, the instance objects have their destructors run. It looks like your warpper is creating an instance from the pointer given by the factory.

Comment: Thanks, so it looks like my workaround is the only way to do it then. Lucky for me the third party authors decided to make the decideWhichSubclassToUse() method public rather than private.